# How can a change the underline color of textField in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have tried to define the Input decoration to change the color of underline of input TextField. But it's not working. can anyone suggest what am i missing here ?

Here is the Code snippet :

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'Username',
    hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
    border: new UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, 
                                      width: 1.0, style: BorderStyle.none ),
    ),
```

Comment: I changes the border style to solid (BorderStyle.solid). But still it didn't work.

Comment: Same problem here. Unable to change the border color of TextField

Answer (score 11):

```dart
decoration: InputDecoration(
  hintText: 'Username',
  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
  enabledBorder: new UnderlineInputBorder(
    borderSide: BorderSide(
      color: Colors.white, 
      width: 1.0, 
      style: BorderStyle.none 
    ),
  ),
),
```

Just change *border* to `enabledBorder`. Hope this help!

Answer (score 7):

We have to use both `enabledBorder` and `focusedBorder`.

- `enabledBorder`: It will work when `TextField` not having focus.
- `focusedBorder`: It will work when `TextField` has the focus.

```dart
enabledBorder: new UnderlineInputBorder(
  borderSide: BorderSide(
    color: Colors.black
  ),
),
// and:
focusedBorder: new UnderlineInputBorder(
  borderSide: BorderSide(
    color: Colors.black
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to put widget hierarchy under **MaterialApp**.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter WebView Demo',
        theme: new ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
          home: new Container(
             **//put widget here.**
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just used -:

```
decoration: InputDecoration(        
  focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(      
    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.cyan),   
  ),    
),
```

it works for me :)

Comment: This only works for focused state and does nothing to the normal state.

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your `TextField` in `Theme` and change `accentColor` like:

```
Theme(
  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(accentColor: Colors.red),
  child: TextField(),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want change that blue line color, used this below code..it works

```
focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 child: TextField(

                  controller: email,
                  enabled: true,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(

                    filled: true,
                    fillColor: Color(0xFFF2F2F2),
                    enabledBorder: new OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.orange)),
                    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.orange),

                    ),
                    hintText: ' Email ',

                    icon: Icon(
                      Icons.email,
                      color: Colors.orange,
                      size: 30.0,
                    ),


                  )

                )
```